# Can a qsub call a script with qsub (recursively)?

Tags: bash, recursion, qsub, torque

I'm trying to write a recursive script that uses qsub, but I'm getting errors after the first iteration. The wrapper script is in perl (script.pl) and looks something like this:

```
script.pl
# creates doONE.sh containing various jobs
# creates submitQSUB.sh
exit 1

less submitQSUB.sh
FIRST=`qsub doONE.sh`
SECOND=`qsub depend=afterok:$FIRST script.sh`
```

The doONE.sh is properly submitted and executed while script.sh is on hold (this works fine). However, it looks like the cluster goes ballistic when attempting to execute script.sh.
I get a weird error that looks like this:

Error in connection to trqauthd (15096)-[could not connect to unix socket /tmp/trqauthd-unix: 111]
Error communicating with clusterhn.cluster.com(172.16.33.254)
Communication failure.

I have tried every possible work around I could think of with no success.
Any input with this would be a huuuuuge help and could give me my sanity back :-(

Comment: What batch system are you using? I believe there's more than one that provides a command named `qsub`. Assuming this is in a cluster environment, you likely can't submit jobs from a compute node.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention we are using Torque. Is there any way I can find out if I'm on a compute node? Again, sorry, but I have limited experience with this. Thanks

Comment: I haven't used Torque in a while, but typically any job you submit will run on one or more compute nodes (since that's what they're for). You probably just need to do all your `qsub`s from the front end node.

Comment: ok, that doesn't sound too bad. Is there a manual that could teach me how to do this? Or a option to add in qsub? Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I'm sure there is. Presumably Torque comes with documentation. As I said, I haven't used it in a long time; any advice I could give you would probably be the result of a Google search that you can do just as well yourself.

Comment: Torque allows you to submit jobs from jobs, but you definitely need trqauthd to be running on the compute nodes. You also need the server to allow qsub submissions from the compute nodes.